# LibGDX - Tiled not rendering entire map

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, tiled

I'm trying to draw a map in [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). The map is created in [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/).

Problem: Click [here](http://prntscr.com/g07whf) to see a picture of what my map looks like while rendered. And [this](http://prntscr.com/g07wtx) picture is what I am trying to render. I tried making a fresh Tiled map with just one layer of grass and a few flowers, when i try to render that, nothing appears at all. How can I fix this to render my entire Tiled map?

Any help is appreciated!

Code:

Game class

```
private GameScreen screen;

@Override
public void create ()
{
    setScreen(new GameScreen());
}

@Override
public void render ()
{
    super.render();
    screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}

@Override
public void dispose ()
{
    super.dispose();
    screen.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    super.resize(width, height);
    screen.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause()
{
    super.pause();
    screen.pause();
}

@Override
public void resume()
{
    super.resume();
    screen.resume();
}

public void setScreen (GameScreen screen)
{
    if (this.screen != null)
        this.screen.hide();
    this.screen = screen;
    if (this.screen != null)
    {
        this.screen.show();
        this.screen.resize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }
}
```

GameScreen class

```
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private FitViewport viewPort;

public GameScreen()
{
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    camera.update();
    viewPort = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    viewPort.setScreenPosition((int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.5f), (int) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.5f));
    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("maps/town.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
}

@Override
public void show()
{

}

public void input()
{

}

public void update(float delta)
{
    input();
    camera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(camera);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mapRenderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    viewPort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause()
{

}

@Override
public void resume()
{

}

@Override
public void hide()
{

}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    map.dispose();
    mapRenderer.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was my tileset png file. The file was 256x8100 or so in resolution. I changed to a more reasonable tileset and do not have any problem at all. I hope anyone else who comes across this problem will see this as a potential fix. :)